# Is there a way to create and destroy muted words using the Twitter API

Tags: python, twitter

I'm trying to write a simple Python application to manage muted words for Twitter. The interface in the browser and the application are cumbersome to use.

Looking through the API documentation, it seems that it is possible to create and destroy muted users but not words. Am I missing something, or is this simply not possible?

I have been trying the python-twitter library but the functionality is missing there too. I realise this is probably an API limitation as opposed to the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The API only has methods for muting users, not words.

Comment: Thanks for the response @andy-piper . I don't suppose you would know if this is every planned to be added?

Comment: There's nothing currently on the [roadmap](https://trello.com/b/myf7rKwV/twitter-api-platform-roadmap), so I can't speculate any further than that.